# Strange condition while trying to get the contact information (EBS)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-ebs

I dont know how to get all the contact information that is stored in HZ_PARTIES.

We have HZ_PARTIES **AND** HZ_PARTY_SITES, both have contact information, right?.

I want to obtain the information from HZ_PARTIES.

The problem is that my query is not working properly, it does not retrieve the information that i want. If i use this query:

```
SELECT
    hp.party_name                              
  , hca.account_number                                           
  , hcp.phone_number
  , hcp.email_address                              
FROM apps.hz_cust_accounts hca
INNER JOIN apps.hz_cust_acct_sites_all hcas ON hca.cust_account_id = hcas.cust_account_id
INNER JOIN apps.hz_party_site hps ON hcas.party_site_id = hps.party_site_id
INNER JOIN apps.hz_locations hl ON hps.location_id = hl.location_id
INNER JOIN apps.hz_parties hp ON hps.party_id = hp.party_id
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            owner_table_id
          , max(case when contact_point_type = 'PHONE' then phone_number end) phone_number
          , max(case when contact_point_type = 'EMAIL' then email_address end) email_address
        FROM hz_contact_points
        WHERE status = 'A'
        AND primary_flag = 'Y'
        AND owner_table_name = 'HZ_PARTIES'
        AND contact_point_type IN ('EMAIL','PHONE')
        GROUP BY 
            owner_table_id
    ) hcp ON hcas.party_site_id = hcp.owner_table_id 
WHERE hcas.status = 'A'
AND hps.status = 'A'
AND hca.status = 'A'
--AND hca.account_number = 'account_number'
;
```

DO NOTE that i am using this condition:

> hcp ON hcas.party_site_id = hcp.owner_table_id

**But this query IS NOT working properly because if i want to find all the contact information for a specific account number, it should return an email but instead it returns NULL**

The fact is if i put this another condition in exchange for the previous one:

> hcp ON hcas.party_site_id = hps.party_site_id

It returns several results for a single account_number, everything is wrong BUT it DOES show the email that i am looking for. 
What is going on here?

Could you please help me to solve this?

PS: Everytime that a customers is created, this PROCEDURE is executed:

https://www.codepile.net/pile/9nzMKy4D

Answer (score 0):

As I know `HZ_PARTIES = HZ_PARTY_SITES` this is one to many relation. So HZ_PARTY_SITES can contain e.g. address "bill to", "ship to" etc.
First of all, check in EBS how many sites the customer has.

I also recommend you page http://etrm.oracle.com/pls/etrm/etrm_search.search. You can check the relation between the EBS's tables there.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVigF.png)

As you can see, the relation between `hcp ON hcas.party_site_id = hcp.owner_table_id`
not exists.

Comment: Thank you for replying!. I dont know, buddy.. i have tried many times without success. I am stuck. Have you got any idea about it? How should i modify my query? :(

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong in the comment above. 

Try change party `) hcp ON hcas.party_site_id = hcp.owner_table_id` to `) hcp ON hps.party_site_id = hcp.owner_table_id` do you have any results? 

As parameter, you should use `AND hps.party_site_number = :p_party_site_number` against `AND hca.account_number = 'account_number'`.

Comment: Actually, party site number is more detailed than account number.

Comment: It shows null emails and it should return one because it does exist :(. Whats wrong?

Comment: It is not working, it shows null emails and what about 'HZ_PARTIES'? I dont know what to do :(